# shading alternate rows with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to shade alternate rows in a table .

The following code

```css
dt:nth-child(4n+1) ,dt:nth-child(4n+1) +dd{
  background-color:silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 tabularData">
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
   <dt>Booking</dt>
   <dd class="ng-binding"></dd> 
   <dt>Shipper</dt>
   <dd class="ng-binding"></dd>
   <dt>Consignee</dt>
   <dd class="ng-binding"></dd>
   <dt>VVD</dt>
   <dd class="ng-binding"></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

But the output currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: but i am trying to shade the entire row

Comment: As far as I can see, the CSS works. It's just that some rows are higher than others, because they contain more lines of text.

Comment: No i am trying to shade the entire row without any white spaces

Comment: You didn't mention that. In that case, how about setting the padding and/or margin on both the dd and the dt to 0. But next time, please state what the problem is. We can't read your mind!

Comment: Thanks ,sorry i wanted to post the images but i cant. I can shade entire row setting the margin and padding to 0 for bith dd and dt . Do u have any idea how to hover the data like below image(option2).                                   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=12yyvl18zmQUcwNrLtd8oOVKs_hL9t8mGeZxp6aLu-Q&usp=sharing

Comment: That should be a different question, not a comment to this one. If this one is solved by my comment, I can post it as an answer, so we'll know this one is solved.

Comment: okay thanks once again

Comment: Right. Now if you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark to the left, then this question is marked as solved, and we can continue with your other problem...

Answer (score 1):

you can use odd even on selected tables 
ex

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color:silver;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color:gold;
}
```

Comment: I just answer what I think is the solution .. thank you for clarification though ..  yeah I think that would'nt solve the problem ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the space between the columns, so the solution is to set the margins on the dd to zero.

```
.col-sm-2.tabularData dd {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi , i am seeing the following where as my requirement is(C S WHOLESALE GROCERS INC ) shold come in one line only.

Comment: Hi  Lister, any idea how to move the extra line of text to single line